# Eliminate $\theta$ from from $\frac{x-k\sin \theta \cot \alpha}{k \cos \theta}=\frac{y-k\cos \theta \tan \alpha}{k \sin \theta}=\frac{z}{c}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck with the following problem :

> Eliminate $\theta$ from 
>   $$\frac{x-k\sin \theta \cot \alpha}{k \cos \theta}=\frac{y-k\cos \theta \tan \alpha}{k \sin \theta}=\frac{z}{c}$$ 
>   to get the following result:
>
> $$k^2(c^2-z^2)^2=c^2\left(\,(cx \tan \alpha-yz)^2+(cy \cot \alpha-zx)^2\,\right)$$

I will be grateful if someone explains the problem which was actually the part of another problem  . Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Where is $y$ in the first equation?

Comment: @Andrei sorry for the typo. corrected..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your line as
$$
\frac{x-k\sin\theta\cot\alpha}{k\cos\theta}=\frac{z}{c}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{y-k\cos\theta\tan\alpha}{k\sin\theta}=\frac{z}{c}.
$$
Manipulate the two equations into
\begin{align*}
cx/k&=c\cot\alpha\sin\theta+z\cos\theta\\
cy/k&=z\sin\theta+c\tan\alpha\cos\theta
\end{align*}
so solving for $\sin\theta,\cos\theta$:
\begin{align*}
k(c^2-z^2)\sin\theta &=c\tan\alpha\cdot cx-z\cdot cy\\
k(c^2-z^2)\cos\theta &=c\cot\alpha\cdot cy-z\cdot cx
\end{align*}
Now remember $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Rearrange the two equations in form $A\sin x+B\cos x=C$

Solve the two simultaneous equations in $\cos x,\sin x$

Use [Proof of $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)=1$ using series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705960/proof-of-sin2x-cos2x-1-using-series)